# How can I drop many BigQuery tables without having to delete each one individually?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dataset that has a few hundred tables in it and I want to DROP most of them. I don't want to have to go and write hundreds of DROP TABLE statements so I was hoping I could employ dynamic SQL. I tried this:

```sql
FOR record IN (
  select dataset_id,table_id
  from   mydataset.__TABLES__
  where <some-criteria-to-get-the-tables-I-want-to-drop>
)
DO
  execute immediate "drop table `?`.`?`" USING record.dataset_id, record.table_id;
END FOR;
```

but that fails with error

> Invalid value: Invalid dataset ID "?". Dataset IDs must be alphanumeric (plus underscores and dashes) and must be at most 1024 characters long. at [1:1]

[image: screenshot of error]

Can someone tell me how I can use dynamic SQL to drop a table? Better still, if someone knows of a better way to drop lots of tables please let me know.

Comment: You can write python or any other script to iterate on a table list and drop them.

Comment: yep, that would work, and that might be what I do. Interested to know why it doesn't work using BQ dynamic SQL though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a table name as a parameter, you'll get an error like below.

> Invalid EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql string `SELECT * FROM ?.?`, Query parameters cannot be used in place of table names at [4:19]

So, what I usually do is using **FORMAT()** function to generate a dynamic query.

```sql
FOR t IN (SELECT dataset_id, table_id FROM testset.__TABLES__)
DO

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  DROP TABLE `%s`.`%s`;
""", t.dataset_id, t.table_id);

END FOR;
```

> Interested to know why it doesn't work using BQ dynamic SQL though.

Below will work and quoted **?** in the query is a just string.

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "SELECT '?', ?, ?" USING 'dataset', 'table';

+-----+-----+---------+-------+
| Row | f0_ |   f1_   |  f2_  |
+-----+-----+---------+-------+
|   1 | ?   | dataset | table |
+-----+-----+---------+-------+
```

If you quote **?** with backticks, a string within backticks will be treated as an **identifier(i.e. column name or variable)** and not be replaced with positional parameters, but an identifier **?** doesn't make sense.

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "SELECT `?`, `?`" USING 'dataset', 'table';
```

Without backticks, below **?** s are replaced with arguments. But will fail with an error.

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "SELECT * FROM ?.?" USING 'dataset', 'table';
```

> Invalid EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql string `SELECT * FROM ?.?`, Query parameters cannot be used in place of table names at [1:19]

Answer (score 0):

I've got solutions with a dynamic SQL as below.
hope it helps you

```
/* DROP Sharded tables  */
DECLARE start_date DATE default '2023-01-02'; 
DECLARE end_date DATE default '2024-01-02';  
DECLARE table_date STRING;
SET table_date = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', start_date); -- YYYYMMDD
LOOP
IF start_date > end_date THEN 
BREAK; 
END IF;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT(

"""
  DROP TABLE `dateset.table_name_%s`; 

"""
,table_date
);
SET start_date = DATE_ADD(start_date , INTERVAL 1 DAY);
SET table_date = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', start_date);
END LOOP;
```